# Zend Framework flexible Form Elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, zend-framework

I'm pretty new to Zend Framework thou i am starting to get the gist of it, however i have once more run into a problem. I want to create a form where it is possible for the user to upload files.

Now the idea is that when the user first visits the page with the form, he/she will see only one form element with wich to upload a file and below that a button to add an additional file and thus an additional element to the form.

I have been looking around and have been suggested to try using JQuery, at this point it is probably good to mention i have never used JQuery, let alone in combination with the Zend Framework.

I have added the ZendX library to the same folder i have the Zend folder in, like this

```
/Zend Framework
 /library
  /Zend
  /ZendX
```

I of course have the library folder included in my include_path variable in the php.ini .
According to what i can make of the Zend Refference guide i need to add the following to my Bootstrap.

```
public function _initJQuery() {
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
    $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
}
```

Having done that i build the following Jquery form in my content module.

```
<?php
class Content_Form_JQueryForm extends ZendX_JQuery_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod('post');
        $this->setName('frm');
        $this->setAction('content/index/add');

        $date1 = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker(
                'date1',
                array('label' => 'Date:')
             );

        $this->addElement($date1);

        $elem = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_Spinner(
                "spinner1", 
                array('label' => 'Spinner:')
        );

        $elem->setJQueryParams(array('min' => 0, 'max' => 1000, 'start' => 100));
        $this->addElement($elem);
    }
}
```

Then in the controller i simply create the form and assign it to a view

```
public function indexAction() {
    $form = new Content_Form_JQueryForm();
        $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

And of course in the appropriate view i echo the form

```
<?php echo $this->form; ?>
```

And when i run the application i get the following error message

Fatal error: Class 'Content_Form_JQueryForm' not found in C:\wamp\www\ZendProject\application\modules\content\controllers\CategoryController.php on line 10

I am clueless as to what i have done wrong and if anyone could help me out it would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i stumbeled upon this tutorial, http://www.jeremykendall.net/2009/01/19/dynamically-adding-elements-to-zend-form/.

It has helped a tremendous amount on understanding how the forms work in Zend.